# SQL, add more informations for columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Ok, I have a problem a bit complicated to explicate and to understand:

I have a postgreSQL DataBase who contains tables with columns, and I want to add some informations about each column, so I make a "service table" who look like this:

```
+---------------+-----------+--------------------+----------+----------+
| ColumnName    |  ucd      |       utype        | datatype |  table   |
+---------------+-----------+--------------------+----------+----------+
| ident         | ucd:ident | utype:EntityId     | char     | Entity   |
| label         | ucd:label | utype:EntityLabel  | char     | Entity   |
| level         | ucd:level | utype:EntityLevel  | int      | Entity   |
| idAct         | ucd:Acti  | utype:ActivityId   | char     | Activity |
| label         | ucd:label | utype:ActivityLb   | char     | Activity |
| ...           | ...       | ...                | ...      | ...      |
+---------------+-----------+--------------------+----------+----------+
```

**The utype and ucd columns are unique**

My problem is:

I do a request on my db.

Exemple: Select * from entity:

Result:

```
+-------+---------+-------+
| ident |  label  | level |
+-------+---------+-------+
|     1 | Entity1 |     1 |
|     2 | Entity2 |     2 |
|     3 | Entity3 |     2 |
+-------+---------+-------+
```

I also want to recover all the informations about my columns in my query whit my service table:

Something like this:

**Ident:** ucd = ucd:ident, utype = utype:EnetityId, datatype=char

**Label:** ucd = ucd:label, utype = utype:EntityLabel, datatype=char

**Level:** ucd = ucd:level, utype = utype:EntityLevel, datatype=int

I know how to have all the columns name of the result of my query, but I don't know how to have all the information about them:

I have that:

```
Select * from servicetable
where columnName = 'queryColumnName'
```

But columnName is not unique in service table so,it may return more than one row.

I hope you have understand my problem. Thank you

Comment: sorry - I did not understand your problem... Maybe a long day...

Comment: You want to recover info from service table in same query with "Select * from entity"? 

If yes, can you please show how result set should looks like?

Comment: My python program take a query in argument example "Select * from entity". With a cursor I can recover the column name of the result of the query. So in this case the cursor will contains colnames('ident','label','level'). So with this I would like to perform something like this "Select * from services where ColumName = "ident". But the problem is they are more than one column name "ident" in my DB.

Answer (score 1):

I really did not understand but I'll try help.

1) You already have some information about tables and columns on postgresql. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
AND table_name   = 'your_table';
```

2) Why dont you add one more filter like " AND table = 'Entity'" ?

Try explain more about your problem.

Comment: My python program take a query in argument example "Select * from entity". With a cursor I can recover the column name of the result of the query. So in this case the cursor will contains colnames('ident','label','level'). So with this I would like to perform something like this "Select * from services where ColumName = "ident". But the problem is they are more than one column name "ident" in my DB.

Comment: It would be difficult to add a filter on the table name because if my query is: "Select * from entity" I don't know how to recover the "entity"